# Which version of MongoDB to install?

Tags: 20.04, 64-bit, cpu, downloads, arm

I need to install MongoDB on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop (dual booted with windows 10), and I can't understand which version I should download from their [website](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community).

Currently I have chosen `4.4.2` as the current version (which I think is the stable version). I can't decide which platform I should chose: `Ubuntu 20.04` or `Ubuntu 20.04 ARM 64`, nor can I decide which package should I chose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please do not hesitate to ask any additional details from me.

Comment: I gave the best answer I could below. However, some might argue that this question is "opinion based", and could thus be closed (since you and only you decide which software to install on your computer).

Comment: I always find it easier to download databases through docker. The initial setup is a little bir longer at first but in the long run it pays as the dev requirements grow.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are not using the version that comes with Ubuntu? I would assume that someone who has such special requirements that they need to use a non-distro version would also know whether their laptop has an AMD64 or an ARM64 CPU.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know mongoDB comes with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I assume the "Community Edition" is the version most people would use.

I also suggest following the [installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) on the website, which I repeat here. This will ensure you get the right package for your architecture (amd64 or arm64).

Install GPG key:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add package list:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

Update sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install MongoDB:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: Does `apt` automatically download and install the correct version for you? And what does the `-y` option do (since google doesn't tell me anything)?

Comment: Yes. And -y is to tell you confirm to do the installation in advance - else you have to press `y` to confirm.