# which mongoDB should I download?

Tags: 20.10, 21.04, database, mongodb

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and I need to download mongoDB Community Server. but in the documentation  they don't say which version is supported.
so please tell me which version I need to download and how I do it?

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 20.10 is in it's last days of support; you've also tagged 21.04 so I'm guessing you already know it's in it's last days - upgrade soon. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) clearly states that the following Ubuntu versions are supported (64-bit versions):

- 20.04 LTS ("Focal")
- 18.04 LTS ("Bionic")
- 16.04 LTS ("Xenial")

This also implies that Ubuntu 20.10 (or 21.04 for that matter) is not officially supported. So what to do then?

My advice would be to install the version of the previous and most recent supported Ubuntu version, which in this case would be 20.04. However, since it's not officially supported there are no guarantees, but I would *assume* it will work.

See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303090/which-version-of-mongodb-to-install/1303092#1303092) for further installation instructions.